# Getting a function to restart itself from the beginning

Tags: function, loops, recursion, goto

I heard using gotos in C++ is a bad practice, especially when dealing with memory management. On the other hand  using a recursive call would stop the current instance of the function and make it wait for the new instance to stop, which could go on for a very long time until it hits a stop condition.

Are there any ways without using recursion or gotos to get a function to stop and restart itself or return to the beginning of a loop?

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly do you wish to do? The solution will vary depending on the required functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use an infinite loop, for example:

```
function dontLikeGotos() {
    while(true) {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

is the same as

```
function yummiGotos() {
    beginning:
        //whatever
    goto beginning;
}
```

For the record, [goto is not available in Java for several reasons](http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Simple.doc2.html#4093).